# What do you think about this play1?

Tags: poker-strategy

[image]

Please share you thought about my play. It looks like most likely I play to aggressive?

Comment: I'll post something in more detail later on, but in short I feel you played this way faster than you should and ultimately felted yourself because of that. But I think it's a nice situation to give some feedback on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert player by any means, I just post my personal thoughts on this.

I don't think you played well. Preflop is ok (though raise to 4*BB maybe a bit high). The flop is dangerous, your opponent might be on a flush draw or straight draw. Continuation bet (8) is ok, also pot-size seems fine to me to avoid giving your opponent the right pot odds if he is on a flush or straight draw. But his over-sized check-raise (9) should have alerted you. Either he slow-played something big, or he is bluffing. Going all-in then (10) means that you are putting him on a bluff. If there is not a very good reason for doing so (like he was bluffing all the time before), this all-in is clearly wrong IMO. Your top pair is just not good enough. I think I would have folded in this situation.